# How to migrate from angular to angular 2.? Challenges that needs to handle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

we have an existing anuglar project which is pretty matured, apparently, now angular 2 is rising with advance features, and improved performance, how can we migrate all the existing work to angular 2
However, we got to know angular 2 but not to forsee the challenges that takes place which can break the existing functionalities

Comment: You need to upgrade to AngularJS 1.5.x first, and then following this guide: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html

Comment: Additionally you can have a look at this https://github.com/ngParty/ng-metadata

Answer (score 3):

My 5 cents to the discussion. When considering a migration of a matured project you should consider all the factors, not only potential benefits of the new technology. For example, angular 2 apps are supposed to be written with TypeScript. While it  works fine with javascript, but gradual migration to typescript means some implications to the product development. In general I'd consider following items:

- developers will take some time to adapt to writing on TS  (also because TS is compiled into the JS for the actual execution in the browser, so console debugging will be a bit harder)
- developers will have to adapt to new paradigms that angular 2 is using. It could be quite a bit of change for the product architecture. So for mature product you may end up with a pretty ugly merge at first as you would probably start to convert gradually. (also meaning that your gain in performance will probably not be that dramatic at first, if any).
- Your development environment will have to be able to handle TS (including any code analysis, test automation and coverage - if used - etc.)
- Libraries, that you are using might not be compatible with Angular 2.

Finally, it is pretty unlikely that angular 1 is going away any time soon. Even if google will stop patching/developing it, I doubt that they will prevent community from doing so.

So first of all, I'd really question of why one should migrate a mature, well working product, to angular 2? You should really have a better idea of how much "better" performance you are expecting to get. Sometimes, "good enough" is good enough, especially when weighted against the cost of migration. Hence, what would be a good start is:

- Understand, what implication to your development processes with the new technology mean (tools, QA, experienced developers, etc)
- Understand, what items in your current product needs improvement and how the new technology is expected to help you
- Do a fast prototype about the most critical areas to proof the concept
- If satisfied with the results of the first 3 items,  consider a rewrite/vs gradual migration.